# SetTimeOutAfter Not working for android Notification

Tags: android, android-automotive

The `setTimeOutAfter` method for notification seems not t be working. My application meets the requirement for minSdk but I do not know why the heads-up-notification dismises from the screen before time elapses.

```
@Singleton
class NotificationHelper @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private var context: Context,
) {

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME"
        private const val BROADCAST_REQUEST_CODE = 0
        private const val NOTIFICATION_TIME_OUT = 30000L
    }

    fun getNotificationManager() =
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    fun createNotification(
        title: String,
        subtitle: String = "",
    ): Notification {
        createNotificationChannel()
        return createNotificationBase(title, subtitle)
            .build()
    }

    fun <T> createNotification(
        title: String,
        actionTitle: String,
        buttonAction: String,
        broadcastReceiver: Class<T>,
        subtitle: String = ""
    ): Notification {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val intent = Intent(context, broadcastReceiver)
            .apply {
                action = buttonAction
            }

        val pendingIntent = pendingIntentWithBroadcast(intent)

        return createNotificationBase(title, subtitle)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_amazon_blue_logo, actionTitle, pendingIntent)
            .build()
    }

    fun sendNotification(notification: Notification, notificationId: Int) {
        getNotificationManager().notify(notificationId, notification)
    }


    private fun pendingIntentWithBroadcast(intent: Intent): PendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            BROADCAST_REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
            .apply {
                lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            }

        getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun createNotificationBase(
        title: String,
        subtitle: String,
    ): NotificationCompat.Builder {
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alexa_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subtitle)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setTimeoutAfter(NOTIFICATION_TIME_OUT)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        
    }


    fun cancelNotification(notificationId:Int) = getNotificationManager().cancel(notificationId)
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to keep heads-up-always-visible `Notification` present on screen for `TimeOutAfter` duration? thats not possible, duration of head-up layout visible on screen is configured in system and you won't override this

`setTimeOutAfter` value will make `Notification` auto-dismiss after this period, but only in API26+ (when introduced). There is no guarantee that `AppCompat`/`AndroidX` version will handle this method in older system versions, common approach is that compat library just won't call `setTimeOutAfter` under the hood on APIs below 26 protecting your app from `NoSuchMethodException` crash. still this isn't same as bringing this feature to older OS versions. but you can do by yourself with e.g.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed (() -> {
    getNotificationManager().cancel(notificationId);
}, NOTIFICATION_TIME_OUT);
```

placed just after `getNotificationManager().notify(...` call

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired result with adding `setOngoing(true)` to the notification builder.